# How to enforce Singleton pattern using enum when class extends Another class

Tags: java, enums

Joshua Bloch says using an enum is the best way to implement singleton:

```
public enum Elvis {
    INSTANCE;

    void someMethod(){
        // implementation
    }

}
```

However, enums cannot `extends` so I guess I will have to refrain from using this approach, or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't use dependency injection (i.e. Spring) and avoid singletons altogether?  If you're not already using Spring and don't want to, there are other implementations of singleton in Java that do not involve enums.

Comment: Implement an interface instead of extending an abstract class.

Comment: @JimGarrison I do not want to use dependency injection at this time, I want to first master doing stuff without it, and then utilize DI.

Comment: @jaco0646 so I cannot use single-element enums to enforce singleton pattern if I want to extend a base class. Okay, that answers my question! Thanks

Comment: An enum can contain another class that implements something. Basically a wrapper pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an enum is just a class, you can have it contain whatever you want (including a single instance of the "extended" class you want) and just expose it. You can control the singleton nature of anything with an enum.

```
public enum Elvis {

    INSTANCE;

    private Object wrappedObject = new Object();


    public Object wrappedObject(){ return wrappedObject; }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Object sortaSingledton = INSTANCE.wrappedObject();//there still can be only one
    }
}
```